# When does laravel make a new query when getting relation

Tags: laravel-5

If i get users company name like this:

```
Auth::users()->company->name
```

And if i do it multiple times on same function, it only makes one query for relation and the rest it uses the value retrieved the first time.

I want to know, how deep this goes and is it possible to make it go deeper. If i, for example, use it in controller and then again on the view, does it make a new query? How can i make it so it would only make the same query once per request (page view)?

*Clarification:
Question was not about eager loading. The question was about how to avoid making the SAME query more than once. Something that is used a lot, like, users company, users tag, users settings. Data that many parts of my application may need but making a new query every time in different parts of my app feels like wasting resources.*

Answer (score 1):

When using Eloquent, if you have a model related to another one, you can eager-load the related models in order to minimize the number of queries.

For example, if you have a `Movie` model related to a `Genre` model (a movie `belongsTo` a genre, a genre `hasMany` movies). If you have 10 movies:

```
$movies = Movie::all();
foreach ($movies as $m) echo $m->genre->name;
// 11 queries are gemerated (get all + 1 per item)
```

whereas :

```
$movies = Movie::with('genre')->get();
foreach ($movies as $m) echo $m->genre->name;
// 2 queries are gemerated (get all movies + get all genres for those movies)
```

Note that you can eager-load multiple and/or nested relations.

e.g.: `with(['genre', 'actors', 'actors.profile'])`

Edit following clarification:

You can then use a middleware which will load your common data. Register that middleware globally so that it can be executed for all requests.

If needed, make an additional facade and a kind of global data manager to make that data available later on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question was not about eager loading. Im well aware of it and use it a lot. But, the question was, how to avoid making the SAME query more than once. Something that is used a lot, like, users company, users tag, users settings. Data that many parts of my application may need but making a new query every time in different parts of my app feels like wasting resources.

Comment: Edited the answer. Middlewares is the way to go.